# Runtime errors on integrating ZXing in my App

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, zxing

I followed a tutorial by [Javier Manzano](http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=244&lang=en) on how to integrate ZXing on my App without passing intent. My App has no errors, except the App crashes when I press "start zxing Activity", it ends up showing many Runtime errors: http://j.mp/MThYu4

Will be really helpful if anyone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it can't find the Activity class. Is it in your classpath?

Comment: It isn't, or else you would not be getting `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: If it's a library(e.g. jar) you're using, then try right-clicking project - Java Build Path. There you should see it.

Comment: @Mighter Thanks, the previous `NoCLassDefFoundError` was solved, now I can't undertand the new issue form LogCat: http://j.mp/KBcTpY

Comment: I guess that  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException is self explanatory.